# Remove-WebConfigurationProperty not removing file extension in request filtering section of IIS

Tags: powershell, iis-7, web-administration

Getting below error message when trying to remove duplicate file extensions from request filtering section of a web application in IIS using Remove-WebConfigurationProperty powershell command.

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty : Filename: \\?\\C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySite\\web.config
Line number: 167
Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.PNG'
At line:1 char:1

+ Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -PSPath 'IIS:\\sites\\MySite' -Filte ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WebConfigurationProperty], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.RemoveConfigurationPropertyCommand
  
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The powershell command that I tried executing is as below :

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -PSPath 'IIS:\\sites\\MySite' -Filter "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/fileExtensions" -Name "." -AtElement @{ fileExtension= '.PNG' }
```

I was expecting this command to remove the duplicate entry but instead it ended up with the error message as mentioned above. Any leads on how to get it resolved will definitely help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ensure you don't have a duplicate web.config file in one of the parent folders.

Comment: Thanks @samwu for responding. 
There are no duplicate web.config(s) however file extensions for request filtering are configured in the web.config of the site, for example: <add fileExtension=".png" allowed="true" />

And then there is a script that happens to add the same extension to all application pools resulting in duplicates. 

What I am trying to do is, to remove the files extensions configured in the web.config of the site using PowerShell commands before adding the new extensions as default to all application pools.

Comment: Can you share your project structure? you can also try add the line below into web.config, It will remove all existing rules to prevent duplication. `<remove path="*" />`